# Java and Tomcat issue

Tags: windows, tomcat, java

All,

At the end of my teather with this and really would appreciate any pointers.

I have a system that was installed with Tomcat 5.5.9 and JRE 6 update 13. My issue is that someone has come along and installed tomcat 6 and JRE 5.

By this simple action they have destroyed the apps that were originally running on the machine.

I have tried to remove the tomcat and java install and from what I can see it has all been removed.

My issue, I am now trying to re-install the oringinal app, but this installer now throughs up a file location error and will not re-install the apache part of the installer.

Can anyone advise of any hidden location were the apache software may have installed components.

This is all installed on Windows Server 2003 R2.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just to check, the original installer installed both Tomcat, the JRE, and your apps?  In that case, you need to copy over the apps and any related settings from the old Tomcat to the new.

Do you still have copies or a backup of the original Tomcat directory?

You need to do the following

- copy any contents of Tomcat 5.5/webapps into Tomcat 6.0/webapps (ignore Tomcat-specific apps like
  manager or host-manager)
- copy the contents of Tomcat 5.5/conf/Catalina/localhost into Tomcat 6.0/conf/Catalina/localhost (again, ignore manager.xml or host-manager.xml)
- review Tomcat 5.5/conf/tomcat-users.xml.  Are there any custom users or groups defined? 
  Copy those over.
- review Tomcat 5.5/conf/server.xml.  Compare with the new server.xml This
  is a little tricky.  Does it seem customized?  The most common change is to change the port from 8080 to 80.

My (slightly) customized server.xml contains this line:

```
 <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

- Finally, you generally need to increase the heap size.  (The default is a very small 64M).  If you have a Tomcat icon in the task tray, click that, otherwise look for the Monitor Tomcat application in the Start menu.  Click the Java tab.  Change the Maximum Memory Pool to something like 512M.

Make sure you stop Tomcat and restart Tomcat after any configuration changes.  I assume the Tomcat service was installed?  (This an option in the Windows Tomcat installer).  Go to the windows services control panel and look for the Apache Tomcat service.